# User-generated fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm building a Djano application which displays a set of images, and a form for each image for recording specific image characteristics. The user initializes a "project", where they specify the set of images that will be displayed for assessment. At project initialization, I'd like to give the user the ability to add custom boolean fields (i.e. a set of checkboxes), but I can't figure out how to build the database models.

For example, a user might initialize `my_project` with `image_A.png`, `image_B.png` and `image_C.png` for assessment. The default form they'll get for each image lets them choose between PASS, FAIL and UNKNOWN. They might wish to add custom fields like "poorly cropped", "over-exposed" or "blurry" (the idea being that the image could be a global PASS, but small failures, specific to the context of this image set, could still be recorded).

Generally, I'm trying to come up with a way to model user-generated fields in Django.

Comment: [django-eav](https://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav) might be what you are looking for...

Comment: Why not just use tags?

Comment: @kubus, What do you mean by tags?

Comment: @ajwood see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you don't need dynamic model fields, instead you can add model, which contains specific attributes for image in project, something like:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    img = models.ImageField()

class ProjectImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey('Image')
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
    flag = models.CharField(choices=PASS_FAIL_UNKNOWN)

class ProjectImageTag(models.Model):
    project_image = models.ForeignKey(ProjectImage)
    value = models.CharField()

class Project(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField('Image', through=ProjectImage)
```

Also, you can store such tags in [json field](https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field) or postgres [hstore field](https://django-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orm-pg-hstore.html) instead of separate table.

**EDIT**

Variation with predefined keys:

```
class ProjectImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey('Image')
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
    flag = models.CharField(choices=PASS_FAIL_UNKNOWN)

class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    img = models.ImageField()

class Project(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField('Image', through=ProjectImage)

class ProjectImageParams(models.Model):
    project_image = models.ForeignKey(ProjectImage, related_name='params')
    key = models.CharField()
    value = models.BooleanField()
```

Params of image may be obtained with ProjectImage().params.all(). And yes, django-eav may be a good option.

Comment: So checking/un-checking the `blurry` box, would insert/drop a row in the ProjectImageTag table?

Comment: Not checking/uncheking, but adding attribute in a text field, maybe http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

Comment: Woah - that `through` parameter is great :D

Comment: Yep :) Added variant for predefined keys